# Eliminating identity wrapper types from Scala APIs

Tags: scala

Suppose I am trying to "abstract over execution":

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

class Operator[W[_]]( f : Int => W[Int] ) {
  def operate( i : Int ) : W[Int] = f(i)
}
```

Now I can define an `Operator[Future]` or `Operator[Task]` etc. For example...

```
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext,Future}
def futureSquared( i : Int ) = Future( i * i )( ExecutionContext.global )
```

In REPL-style...

```
scala> val fop = new Operator( futureSquared )
fop: Operator[scala.concurrent.Future] = Operator@105c54cb

scala> fop.operate(4)
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> res0
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(16))
```

Hooray!

But I also might want a straightforward synchronous version, so I define somewhere

```
type Identity[T] = T
```

And I can define a synchronous operator...

```
scala> def square( i : Int ) : Identity[Int] = i * i
square: (i: Int)Identity[Int]

scala> val sop = new Operator( square )
sop: Operator[Identity] = Operator@18f2960b

scala> sop.operate(9)
res2: Identity[Int] = 81
```

Sweet.

But, it's awkward that the inferred type of the result is `Identity[Int]`, rather than the simpler, straightforward `Int`. Of course the two types are really the same, and so are identical in every way. But I'd like clients of my library who don't know anything about this abstracting-over-execution stuff not to be confused.

I could write a wrapper by hand...

```
class SimpleOperator( inner : Operator[Identity] ) extends Operator[Identity]( inner.operate ) {
  override def operate( i : Int ) : Int = super.operate(i)
}
```

which does work...

```
scala> val simple = new SimpleOperator( sop )
simple: SimpleOperator = SimpleOperator@345c744e

scala> simple.operate(7)
res3: Int = 49
```

But this feels very boiler-platey, especially if my abstracted-over-execution class  has lots of methods rather than just one. And I'd have to remember to keep the wrapper in sync as the generic class evolves.

Is there some more generic, maintainable way to get a version of `Operator[Identity]` that makes the containing type disappear from the type inference and API docs?

Answer (score 3):

This more of long comment rather than an answer...

> But, it's awkward that the inferred type of the result is Identity[Int], rather than the simpler, straightforward Int. Of course the two types apparent types are really the same, and so are identical in every way. But I'd like clients of my library who don't know anything about this abstracting-over-execution stuff not to be confused.

This sounds like you want to convert `Indentity[T]` back to `T`... Have you considered type ascription?

```scala
scala>def f[T](t: T): Identity[T] = t

scala>f(3)
// res11: Identity[Int] = 3

scala>f(3): Int
// res12: Int = 3

// So in your case
scala>sop.operate(9): Int
// res18: Int = 81
```

Comment: Type annotations like this do work fine! It's a good suggestion, thank you. I use them to cheat in my example code, so that the result types look simple. But they put the burden on users of the library to understand that complicated looking types are really simple types, so that this kind of nudge of the compiler can work. I'm wondering if there's some way for naive users not to have to understand all this.

Answer (score 2):

As Steve Waldman suggested in comments given `type Identity[T] = T`, the types `T` and `Identity[T]` really are identical without any ceremony, substitutable and transparent at call sites or anywhere else. For example, following works fine out-of-the-box

```
sop.operate(9) // res2: cats.Id[Int] = 81
def foo(i: Int) = i
foo(sop.operate(9)) // res3: Int = 81
```

[`extract`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/d99325153b1b7b4d3aca1141935d6b67182a511d/core/src/main/scala/cats/Comonad.scala#L28) from Cats is the dual of `pure` and extracts the value from its context, so perhaps we could provide similar methods for users not familiar with the above equivalence *(like myself if you see my previous edit)*.

Comment: With this kind of identity type, defined as `type Identity[T] = T` or `type Id[T] = T`, the types `T`, `Identity[T]`, and `Id[T]` really are identical without any ceremony, substitutable and transparent at call sites or anywhere else. They just _look_ scary and complicated to users who may not understand that. But it's a good idea to define something like an `extract` or `unwrap` operation for them. Users who don't understand the equivalence at least then have an easy way back out to what they do understand. Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done by providing types explicitly, but still looks magical for external users investigating method signature.

```
type Identity[T] = T

def square( i : Int ):Int = i * i

class Operator[W[_], T <: W[Int] ]( f : Int => T ) {
  def operate(i : Int):T = f(i)
}

val op = new Operator[Identity,Int](square)

op.operate(5)
//res0: Int = 25
```

Works for `new Operator[Future,Future[Int]]` as well.